# LaTex: Adding cell padding to a text frame

Tags: framed

I'm trying to create a box as below in LaTeX.

```
\framebox[40em][c]{ I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is my own unless referenced.
}
```

I want a little bit padding between the text and the frame as shown in figure. I tried `\vspace` and putting line breaks at the beginning.

Also I can't put line breakers when I'm using `\framebox` to create the box. Can someone please advise me?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`\parbox` or environment `minipage` can be used to put vertical material in a horizontal box like `\fbox` or `\framebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering
\fbox{%
  \parbox{20em}{I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is
  my own unless referenced.}%
}

\medskip

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
\fbox{%
  \parbox{20em}{I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is
  my own unless referenced.}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The padding is controled by dimen register `\fboxsep` and the line width of the frame by `\fboxrule`.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package which easily gives you frames in which you can control the individual padding to the left, to the right, to the top and bottom, among many other attributes. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myframe}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  #1
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is my own unless referenced.
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}[width=30em]
I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is my own unless referenced.
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}[width=30em,top=10pt,bottom=10pt,left=20pt,right=20pt]
I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is my own unless referenced.
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}[width=30em,top=20pt,bottom=20pt,left=20pt,right=20pt,arc=10pt,auto outer arc]
I certify that the work presented in the dissertation is my own unless referenced.
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]